# Filter by part of date

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My model

```
class BaseArticleModel(polymodel.PolyModel):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    created_at = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = db.DateProperty(auto_now=True)

class News(BaseArticleModel):
    body = db.TextProperty()
```

I need get rows by last month. I use interactive console. When to do filter like this

```
q = News.all().filter('created_at.month = ',datetime(2011,04,01).month)
print q[0].title
```

I get `"IndexError: The query returned fewer than 1 results"`

Answer (score 3):

I was get something like your solution in the Google App Engine group.

```
class BaseArticleModel(polymodel.PolyModel):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    created_at = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = db.DateProperty(auto_now=True)
    @db.ComputedProperty
    def CM(self):
        return self.created_at.month
```

Answer (score 1):

To query based on a month, I'd suggest adding an additional derived field to your model which is automatically updated when the object gets saved:

```
class BaseArticleModel(polymodel.PolyModel): 
    title = db.StringProperty() 
    created_at = db.DateProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = db.DateProperty(auto_now=True)

    # will be auto-generated
    created_at_month = db.IntegerProperty()

    def put(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.created_at_month = self.created_at.month
        super(BaseArticleModel, self).put(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Edit**: Re-reading your question, it looks like you're not really looking for all posts from a given month (e.g. October of any year), but rather just posts in a single month. If that's the case then you should be able to just revise your query to a simple comparison:

```
# get News posted in April, 2011
all_news = News.all()
all_news.filter('created_at >=', datetime(2011, 4, 1))
all_news.filter('created_at <', datetime(2011, 5, 1))
```

**Edit #2**: [As noted by Nick below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517874/filter-by-part-of-date/5517937#comment-6288057), overriding `put()` would be bad form, since it would only be effective when called as a bound method, and will NOT work with `db.put()` or other ways of saving to the datastore.

Comment: Don't override put to set properties - put is only called if you call it directly - so, eg, `db.put(myinstance)` will fail to update it.